# When implementing Java Socket communication, there is no server response

Tags: java, sockets, javafx

I wanted to implement a multi-chat room, so I was implementing a code that checks for duplicates of nicknames when entering.

However, contrary to expectations, even if the client sends the value, the server processes it, but it stops even before receiving it from the client.

DemoClient - clientStart (function) - receive(), you can check how DemoClient processes values by commenting on receive.

I really want to know if there's anything that I didn't know during socket communication.

DemoClient.class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class DemoClient extends Application  {
    Socket socket;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfNickname;

    @FXML
    void onClickSubmit(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
            clientStart();
            send(tfNickname.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ClientUI.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Client");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public void send(String str) throws IOException {
        //Client -> Server
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(out);

            dout.writeUTF(str);
            System.out.println("send >> " +  str);

            dout.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
    }

    public void receive()  {
        //Server -> Client
        while(true){
            try{
                InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);

                Boolean bool = din.readBoolean();
                System.out.println("response to Server >> " +  bool);

                din.close();
                in.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch(Exception e){
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    public void clientStart() throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 5005);
//        receive(); //The problematic part.
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  { launch(args); }
}
```

ClientUI.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.DemoClient">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="tfNickname" layoutX="58.0" layoutY="48.0" />
      <Button layoutX="213.0" layoutY="48.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickSubmit" text="확인" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

DemoServer.class

```
package application;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DemoServer {
    private static ArrayList userList = new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5005);
        System.out.println("Running server...");


        while(true){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            //Client -> Server
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);

            String nickname = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("nickname = " + nickname);

            boolean isUser = false;
            if(userList.contains(nickname)){
                isUser = true;
            } else {
                userList.add(nickname);
            }

            System.out.println("[Input User]");
            System.out.println("[User IP] " + socket.getInetAddress());
            System.out.println("[UserList] " + userList);

            //Server -> Client
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(out);
            System.out.println("isUser >> " + isUser);
            dout.writeBoolean(isUser);

            System.out.println();
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            socket.close();
            }
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: As soon as you call receive, you will enter an infinite loop, hanging the JavaFX thread and all UI and event processing until you get a socket exception.  You might want to implement your communication framework without JavaFX, thoroughly testing that way, then study up on JavaFX concurrency to see how to bring it into a JavaFX program safely.

Comment: Oracle wrote a tutorial on [creating a chat application with JavaFX and web sockets](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/BinaryWebSocket/binaryWebSocket.html). The implementation is different from yours, but perhaps if you study it, you may learn some techniques that can assist you.

Comment: “even if the client sends the value, the server processes it, but it stops even before receiving it from the client” -> this makes no sense.  How could the server process a value it hasn’t received?

Comment: In`DemoClient` where is `launch()` defined?

Comment: Normally, in socket programming, the client and server code for sending and receiving should be in separate threads.

Comment: @kiner_shah [`launch()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.String...)) is defined in the [`Application`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) superclass.

Comment: As an aside: Don't use your `Application` subclass as an FXML controller; use a separate class for the controller.